# Adobe CQ /libs/foundation/components/parbase usage?

Tags: adobe, aem

I am just trying to understand when to use "foundation/components/parbase" as supertype?

I am creating a custom component which would be dragged from sidekick and dropped onto parsys area.

Do I need to use super type of custom component to be "foundation/components/parbase" ? If so, for what purpose would I use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of Parbase component:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400388/what-is-the-use-of-parbase-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parbase component contains few scripts for rendering images and text. Hence when you extend this component, you can leverage those scripts without the need to duplicate the logic for the same.

For example, the `img.GET.java` helps in rendering the image when the resource is requested using the `.img` selector.

It is not mandatory that you need to extend parbase for all your components. Instead you can extend specific components which provides most of the desired functionality and requires less tweaking.

However if there is no such OOTB component available to extend and you are developing the custom component from scratch, extending parbase doesn't do any harm.

Comment: Thank you Rakhi for explaining in plain english. :)